# Bootstrap 3 col-m-n not functional

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I'm sure there have been a million questions of this bent, but I'm having trouble getting the columns in my grid layout to work. I'm currently trying to recreate [this website](http://manfield.net.au/) using Bootstrap 3.3.5, but for some reason, my columns haven't been showing up. I'm pretty sure they're nested properly--obviously there's something I'm missing!

Here's the code I'm working with:

http://jsbin.com/kipaha/edit?html,output

Comment: Have you added the `bootstrap.js` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're very close with the class name but you have:

```
col-m-4
```

and the proper class would be:

```
col-md-4
```

like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

Answer (score 1):

You used this class:

```
<div class="col-m-6">
```

This class doesn't exist. [Twitter bootstrap provides 4 classes with these prefixes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options):

- `col-xs-N`
- `col-sm-N`
- `col-md-N`
- `col-lg-N`

Where `N` is the width of the column from `1` to `12`.

So you should use this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```